# git : multiple master HEAD threads in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse

I have just started using git in eclipse and frankly it is has had an enormous impact on my development.

On each occasion I make a change I commit it and  comment it.

The way I was doing this  was  by first staging on command line terminal using

git add .

Then committing it in eclipse
by
While  root project name selected in eclipse project explorer -> right click -> team -> commit.

I seemed to have done something wrong.

If I select one of the sub directories I have another thread appearing in git history window with master HEAD and a thread of changes below it.

if I select one of the files I have aldo another thread beginning with master HEAD and list of changes below it.

I should only have one thread so that when the repository is select in git repository window or the root in the project explorer I  have just this one thread.

Also if I make changes  they get added to these two unwanted threads rather than my main thread.

How can I  merge back these unwanted threads so that I only have one thread  ?

Comment: Check your History View's Filter settings: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_the_Filter_Settings

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got into that state, but there is no reason you can't perform all of your git operations from within Eclipse.  Just use the "Git Staging" view for all operations.  Your step of "git add" simply consists of moving a newly changed (or added) file from the "Unstaged changes" panel to the "Staged changes" panel.